# Скрипт работает, а addon с тем же кодом - нет

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, addons

Проект опубликован как веб-дополнение для Таблиц.
Доверенный тестировщик (он же редактор) запускает add-on и он не работает. Получает сообщение "Вы не можете выполнить это действие. Запросите доступ у владельца файла".
Если в этой же таблице редактор запускает встроенный скрипт с этим же кодом, то всё работает.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sName = ss.getName();
  var eds = ss.getEditors();
  var owner = eds[0];
  var ed = eds[1];
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Task");
  var emailAddress = owner.getEmail();
  var subject = "Done! - " + sName;
  var localDate = Date();
  sheet.getRange(12, 2, 1, 1).setValue(localDate);
  var values = sheet.getRange("B2:K11").getValues();
  var message = "#" + values + "#" + localDate + "#";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  ss.removeEditor(ed);
```

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, куда копать.

**Upd**
Я удалил строку из remEditor.js:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Изменил номер версии в manifest.json. 
Упаковал снова в архив zip и загрузил в Store. Проверил, обновилась ли версия надстройки у редактора - да, обновилась. 
Редактор запустил аддон и получил ту же ошибку.

После этого я удалил строки:

```
ss.removeEditor(ed); 
sheet.getRange(12, 2, 1, 1).setValue(localDate);
```

и повторил все манипуляции. 
Редактор запустил аддон и снова получил ту же ошибку.

Значит, дело не в активных действиях с листом и правами?

Comment: Что хоть за аддон? Какой код внутри? Может он затрагивает что-то, на что доступа нет у вашего тестировщика.

Comment: @СергейПряничкин Если тестировщик, он же редактор таблицы, запускает встроенный в таблицу скрипт с тем же кодом, то всё работает.
Если запускает аддон, то получает ошибку. 
В такой ситуации разве может быть дело в коде?

Comment: Борис, приведите, пожалуйста полный минимальный листинг программы для того, чтобы мы смогли повторить ошибку.

Comment: @oshliaer спасибо за конструктив.
Я уже частично решил задачу. Меня навели на правильный путь люди добрые на англоязычном SO. 
Вот [ссылка](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-editor-v-2/egkdgppledgjkibhajmoeomhklbkbmlc) на аддон. Полный код - в его описании. 

Почему решение частичное.
Во-первых, я хотел обойтись без меню, с помощью кнопки, т.к. на мобилах меню неудобно (как и сайдбар), а кнопку можно сделать большой.
Второе - новый редактор вынужден снова включать аддон, хотя владелец это уже сделал.
Подскажете, можно ли запускать аддон с кнопки?